# Vim Syntax file: defining keywords to ignore whitespace

Tags: vim, vim-syntax-highlighting, sas-jmp

I would like to create a vim syntax file where either:

1. White space is included in keywords.
2. White space is ignored in keywords.

Either would work for my purpose, which is to create a JMP scripting language (JSL) syntax file. In JMP, whitespace is ignored in keywords, so `New Column("Col1")` and `NewColumn(`Col1`) are identical. The former format, with the space, is the standard.

Comment: did you ever complete/publish such syntax file?

Comment: I cobbled something together that worked well enough, but it wasn't good enough to publish, and I no longer have access to it after switching jobs. Sorry.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can `syntax match` with a regular expression to include optional whitespace:

```
:syntax match GROUPNAME /\<New\s*Column\>/
```

Note, that this is not *quite* the same as `syntax keyword`, because `keyword` has higher priority. In practice, it rarely matters.